# Redrawing elements ignores user-scalable=0 in Android Browser. Why?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, redraw

**This is the meta tag**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

**Problem** - I wanted to force a redraw (to solve another problem) when the orientation was changed by hiding and unhiding a container `<div id="redraw>"`. Once redraw occurs however, the Android browser now allows me to zoom in even though I had set `user-scalable=0`.

Why is this? My guess was that Android had changed the meta tag on redraw by setting `user-scalable=1`. But this was not the case, because as you can see in the function `redrawOrientation()` below, I change the meta tag back to default. I did this by redrawing on landscape orientation only.

This seems like a bug to me. Can anyone suggest a reason for this issue?

**Javascript**

```
 function redrawOrientation() {

      viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");

      if (Math.abs(window.orientation) === 90) {      

           $('#redraw').hide().show(0);
           viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0');

           alert("Landscape: maximum-scale=2.0");

      } else {       

           //$('#redraw').hide().show(0);
           viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0');   

           alert("Portrait: maximum-scale=1.0");

      }
 }

 window.onorientationchange = redrawOrientation;
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="redraw">
     <div id="sidebar"></div>
     <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `user-scalable=no`.

Comment: @Broxzier Just tried, same result. Zoom enabled once redraw occurs.

Comment: Just found out... Android Chrome respects this and does not re-enable zoom after redrawing.

Answer (score 3):

Well... after 3 days of frustration I finally find out what's causing this, and I can't say I'm very happy. Mostly, because the problem was the deletion of one line.

I started deleting everything piece meal until the problem went away. I found out when I deleted normalize.css that I no longer got zoom in issues after orientation change.

This piece of CSS in normalize.css caused the issue in Android Browser.

```
a:active,
a:hover {
     outline: 0;
}
```

Removing `outline: 0` also fixed zoom problem. Giving the property of `0` to `outline` is not one of the allowable values per the W3C (http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/outline-style).

The only allowable values are `none dotted dashed solid double groove ridge inset outset inherit`. Although `0` may evaluate the same as `none`, for whatever reason it breaks zooming.

**Recap**

If anyone else ever stumbles here trying to figure out why their Android browser appears to be re-enabling `user-scalable=0` to `user-scalable=1`, these are the reasons why:

1. You have some sort of CSS issue in defining your `<div>` elements - try playing around with `position: fixed / absolute / relative` until it is fixed.
2. You are experiecing hte same problem described in this post. Using normalize.css with `outline: 0`

I hope this helps save someone 3 days of their life.