# WordPress in mobile browser still allows zoom

Tags: css, html, wordpress, mobile-safari

When I use WordPress Admin Panel in a Mobile browser such as iOS Safari or Android Chrome it allows me to pinch to zoom. When I checked the HTML I see that the below script is in the `<head>` which in the past has worked for me to prevent the user being able to scale.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Am I missing anything else here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

It was missing

```
, user-scalable=0
```

Comment: Still scales within the mobile

Comment: you may try `user-scalable=no`. anyway i found [something here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934048/redrawing-elements-ignores-user-scalable-0-in-android-browser-why). hope it  can hel